# My Linux VM wont start due to wrong chkconfig startup priorities set on oracle db and weblogic

Tags: linux, chkconfig

I have setup startup scripts for Oracle database 11gR2 and WebLogic 10.3.6 with below chkconfig values but WebLogic tried to start first instead of Oracle database. My application is dependent of database to be up and due to the reason that database is not up yet, the boot window of Linux VM is stuck indefinitely at the same location trying to start WebLogic. How can I fix this issue ?

For WebLogic, chkconfig: 345 85 20
and for Oracle DB, chkconfig: 345 99 10

Linux should have started Oracle first but in this case, it tried to start WebLogic. How can I correct it now that I can't even login to my VM.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: ssh into the VM?

Comment: Oh yes! I can login. I didn't even read the output which clearly says sshd is started OK. Thank you for pointing out. Is my chkconfig start priority correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. Since sshd was successfully started, I logged into my VM through ssh and corrected chkconfig.